# Parsing a list from source page

Tags: python, greasemonkey

**** Disclaimer ****
I have a concussion so I can't spend the amount of time I desire to do all the research I would have done by myself and wanted to be guided not spoon feed I can only use one of my 4 screens and start getting dizzy and lose the mouse cursor after 30-45 minutes.  Also my filter on thoughts is broken so I'm sorry if I offend anyone, I know it happens because my girlfriend left me for this reason.
I added the TAG python to the question, hope you find it in your heart to help me if not, then I understand why I'm still in the top 5% of users and will ask Skeet to help me.
*************** End disclaimer *******

I've taken out the link, since it was flagged, before the link would have been edited out, is this the new SO, I didn't remember this community being like that.  So before closing the question can you edit out the parts you don't like and comment me so I can edit my question properly please really appreciated, you can look at my profile, I helped a lot in the past, my post still get me reputation, not looking for more reputation trying to find my dog that's all, the link is from the kennel club of america, I just put it in there because I thought it would help very sorry mister question closer.

I haven't been on this site since I changed careers and started to work on movie sets. A couple weeks ago, I flashed on a memory of my Doberman when I as a little boy, that we had to sell sadly

I have been on a doberman forum trying to figure out how to retrace him, he was sold in 1976

I was given a List of Dogs, each dog has a mother and father, and both parents have both parents.

I would like to go through that list of dogs, parents, parents of parents etc.. As I was clicking through the first dogs ancestry, that took way too much time, so I decided to ask you guys for help and tips to perform said task.

I worked more on the back end than the front, creating msbuild script, wix installers and reading Jon Skeet posts, is that still a thing?

I thought of using Python to do this

PSEUDO CODE

```
For each item in list
   Doggy.ParseDoggyInfo (CurrentIndex) 

Doggy.DumpInBaggy(FileName)
```

That way I will have the full genealogy of each dog in the list.  I'm still trying to remember the registration tattoo he had, but can't yet because I at the age of 4 years old trying to figure out what the code of his tattoo meant I wasn't able to, thus having no handle or hook on that memory

I know that ParseDoggyInfo is a recursive function that I will set the limit to around 1968, because I think my dog was younger but want to have more data in the dump file than miss the hit I want.

Comment: Link of original search page  http://dobequest.org/search.php
If it's okay to put here, if not please say

Comment: PLease Obi wans you're are only hope!